# Problemas com slide owl-carrousel

Tags: javascript, html5, css3, owl-carousel

Estou desenvolvendo um site e estou utilizando o owl-carrousel2 porém estou com um problema com a opção `nav` gostaria que ela aparece-se no meu site eu simplesmente no js eu adiciono essa lina `nav:true` so que mesmo assim ele não aparece quando eu olho no console os meus `navs` aparecem com uma `class` chamada `disable` que da um `display:none` nos navegadores do slide sei que no caso é somente dar um `display:block` na linha do `css` mais não acho isso uma boa pratica se eu utilizar o `nav:true` ele teria que aparecer por padrão sem precisar de uma edição via `css`segue o o que é exibido no console e o código:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

JS:

```
$('.slide-camp').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    autoplay:false,
    autoplayTimeout:5000,
    navText : ['<i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>','<i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>'],
    rewindNav : true,
    slideSpeed: 300,
    singleItem: true, transitionStyle: "fade",
    autoHeight:true,
    responsiveClass:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1,
            nav:false
        },
        600:{
            items:3,
            nav:false
        },
        1000:{
            items:4,
            nav:true
        }
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="item">
                        <div class="box-one">
                            <img src="images/slide-04.jpg" class="image-slide-1" alt="Campo" />
                            <div class="overlay">
                                <div class="text-center content-box">
                                    <h3 class="title">Society club</h3>
                                    <p class="text">Quadra society</p>
                                    <ul class="list-inline list-unstyled classifications">
                                        <li><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
                                        <li><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
                                        <li><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
                                        <li><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
                                        <li><i class="fa fa-star-half-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Procurando entre diversas documentações, consegui encontrar uma possível solução:

Ao invés de declarar como `nav:true`, declare como `navigation:true` e provavelmente aparecera o `next` e o `prev`, e a partir daí, é só manipular os itens através das classes `.owl-prev` e `.owl-next.`

**Exemplo:**

**JS:**

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    navigation:true,
    autoplay:false,
    autoplayTimeout:5000

});

$('.owl-next').html('Avançar');
$('.owl-prev').html('Recuar');
```

> Note que ao invés de NAV eu declaro `navigation:true`, e após, manipulo
>   o texto inserindo um HTML via js.

Espero ter ajudado! Abs